# Markov chain on complete seperable metric space

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains

$X(n)$ is a Markov chain on $X$, a separable, complete metric space, is the following chain  Feller?
i.e for every $f\in C(\mathcal X, \mathbb R)$, the map $x\mapsto \mathbb E ( f(X(1))| X(0)=x)$ is continuous? And, for every
$X(0)=x\in \mathcal X$ and for any $f\in f\in C(\mathcal X, \mathbb R)$, do we have $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{k+1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}f(X(j))=\int f(x)\pi(dx)$, forsome $\pi$ unique invariant measure.

We can think of the chain is generated by $X(n)=f_{\theta}(X(n-1))$ where $\theta\in \Theta$, $f_\theta$ is a family of Lipschitz maps on $X$.$\Theta$  is finite set say $\{1,\dots,p\}$, $m$ is a probability distribution on $\Theta$ such that probability of selecting $f_\theta$ is $m(\theta)$.

For $X$ compact I know, a result kind of related to this, ref[1](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177705810)

Comment: You haven't told us what the chain actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain is Feller, since
$$E[f(X(1)) \mid X(0)=x] = \sum_{\theta \in \Theta} m(\theta) f(f_\theta(x))$$
and the right side is just a finite linear combination of continuous functions of $x$.

It does not have to have be ergodic, since, for instance, such a chain can simply be uniform motion to the right, i.e. on the state space $\mathbb{R}$, $X(n) = n$ (take $\Theta = \{\theta_0\}$ to have one point, and $f_{\theta_0}(x) = x+1$).  Then the limit you are taking is $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k+1} \sum_{j=0}^k f(j)$ and you can certainly find continuous functions $f$ for which this diverges (something like $f(x) = \sin(\log x))$ will probably work).

Comment: I think you should ask that as a new question.  I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: That seems to me like a reasonable question.